# php rtrim is not resulting correctly

Tags: php

```
<?php
$ret="Updated Date: 07-feb-2014 Creation Date: 07-feb-2014 Expiration Date: 07-feb-2015 >>> Last update of whois database: Tue, 30 Sep 2014 06:37:52 UTC <<< NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring registrar";
   $str=explode("Creation Date:",$ret); echo rtrim($str[1],"Expiration");

?>
```

this is my php code, i used rtrim but it returns

```
07-feb-2014 Expiration Date: 07-feb-2015 >>> Last update of whois database: Tue, 30 Sep 2014 06:37:52 UTC <<< NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring regis
```

but i need `07-feb-2014` as output, what can i do for this.

Comment: explode $str1 again on Expiration Date: e.g. $str2=explode("Expiration Date:",$str[1]); echo ($str2[0]);

Comment: `rtrim()` works on single characters, not strings.

Comment: double explode or preg_match, your choice.

Comment: but in the below example, <?php
$str = "Hello World!";
echo $str . "<br>";
echo rtrim($str,"World!");
?> it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
$ret="Updated Date: 07-feb-2014 Creation Date: 07-feb-2014 Expiration Date: 07-feb-2015 >>> Last update of whois database: Tue, 30 Sep 2014 06:37:52 UTC <<< NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring registrar";
       $str=explode("Creation Date:",$ret);
$str2=explode("Expiration Date:",$str[1]); echo ($str2[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to match the string using a regular expression?

The code below will output what you want:

`$ret="Updated Date: 07-feb-2014 Creation Date: 07-feb-2014 Expiration Date: 07-feb-2015 >>> Last update of whois database: Tue, 30 Sep 2014 06:37:52 UTC <<< NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring registrar";`

`preg_match("/.*Creation Date: (.*?) /", $ret, $matches);
echo $matches[1];`

More Info here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: In my experience one tries to avoid regular expressions as much as one can. Regular expressions are complex operations that MAY require more cpu time than you might imagine. So when a solution is achievable in a simple way without a RE, just use it.
For more: http://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/

Comment: You really shouldn't treat regular expressions as the devil, as they are a very powerful tool. They can be resource expensive depending the case..

In our example "Creation Date: " only has one match in the string and the string is relatively small so I don't think that the performance will be affected

On the other hand if you use expressions like the "(x+x+)+y" example in the page you shared, I agree that the cpu will be stressed.

But that is just a use case that has nothing to do with my answer